# Typescript and wrong event type onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got this warning:

```
TS2322: Type '(values: IEmailTemplate, form: FormApi<IEmailTemplate, Partial<IEmailTemplate>>) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(values: IEmailTemplate, form: FormApi<IEmailTemplate, IEmailTemplate>, callback?: ((errors?: SubmissionErrors) => void) | undefined) => void | SubmissionErrors | Promise<SubmissionErrors>'. 
Types of parameters 'form' and 'form' are incompatible. 
Type 'FormApi<IEmailTemplate, IEmailTemplate>' is not assignable to type 'FormApi<IEmailTemplate, Partial<IEmailTemplate>>'. 
The types of 'getState().active' are incompatible between these types. 
Type 'string | number | symbol | undefined' is not assignable to type 'keyof IEmailTemplate | undefined'. 
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof IEmailTemplate | undefined'.  index.tsx(24, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onSubmit' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & EmailEditorProviderProps<any>'
```

This is how I add event function:

```
onSubmit={onSubmit}
```

And this is my function:

```
// save callback
  const onSubmit = useCallback(
    async (
      values: IEmailTemplate,
      form: FormApi<IEmailTemplate, Partial<IEmailTemplate>>,
    ) => {
      // Rest of code...
      

    },
    [dispatch, history, id, initialValues],
  );
```

I used like this and its not warned:

```
onSubmit={() => onSubmit}
```

but click does not fired my function.

Types:

```
onSubmit?: Config<IEmailTemplate, Partial<IEmailTemplate>>['onSubmit'];

export interface FormApi<
  FormValues = Record<string, any>,
  InitialFormValues = Partial<FormValues>,
>
```

How to clean code without waring?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided `onSubmit` function, it seems that the `form` parameter is expected to be of type `FormApi<IEmailTemplate, Partial<IEmailTemplate>>`. However, the error suggests that the expected type is `FormApi<IEmailTemplate, IEmailTemplate>`.

To resolve this issue, you can adjust the type of the `form` parameter in the `onSubmit` function to match the expected type. Here's an updated version of the `onSubmit` function:

```js
const onSubmit = useCallback(
  async (
    values: IEmailTemplate,
    form: FormApi<IEmailTemplate, IEmailTemplate>, // Adjusted the type of `form` parameter
  ) => {
    // Rest of your code...
  },
  [dispatch, history, id, initialValues],
);
```

By making this change, the `form` parameter will be compatible with the expected type, and the TypeScript error should be resolved.

---

If you're not getting any warnings with `onSubmit={() => onSubmit}`, it means that the type mismatch issue is resolved. However, the function is not being called because you are passing a function reference (`onSubmit`) inside another anonymous arrow function (`() => onSubmit`).

To fix this, you should directly pass the `onSubmit` function without wrapping it in an additional arrow function. Here's the updated code:

```
onSubmit={onSubmit}
```

By making this change, the `onSubmit` function will be called directly when the event is triggered.

Regarding your question about cleaning the code without warnings, you can consider the following suggestions:

1. Remove unnecessary comments: Clean up any commented-out code or deprecated comments to make the code more readable.
2. Check for unused variables or imports: Remove any variables or imports that are not being used in your code.
3. Ensure consistent and appropriate typing: Make sure the types of variables, function parameters, and return values are consistent and match the expected types.

Following these practices should help in keeping your code clean and reducing warnings.

Comment: TS2322: Type '(values: IEmailTemplate, form: FormApi<IEmailTemplate, IEmailTemplate>) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(values: IEmailTemplate, form: FormApi<IEmailTemplate, IEmailTemplate>, callback?: ((errors?: SubmissionErrors) => void) | undefined) => void | SubmissionErrors | Promise<SubmissionErrors>'.

Comment: onSubmit is a function and you are not allowed to trigger the process without brackets use brackets after onSubmit
`onSubmit={()=> onSubmit()}`
also try onClick to trigger your function

Comment: This is valid:
`onSubmit={(value, form)=> onSubmit(value, form)}`
 but stil I got warning on form value like this:
TS2345: Argument of type 'import("/node_modules/final-form/dist/index").
FormApi<IEmailTemplate, IEmailTemplate>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/node_modules/final-form/dist/index").
FormApi<import("/src/typings/index").IEmailTemplate, import("/src/typings/index").IEmailTemplate>'.